# Custom SessionSecurityTokenCache with forms authentication

Tags: .net-4.5, wif, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to combine a few things. I'm using the ideas presented at [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/02/09/replacing-asp-net-forms-authentication-with-wif-session-authentication-for-the-better/) so that I can take advantage of claims while not having to have an STS. I'm also trying to create my own token cache documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytokencache.aspx) so that things will work in a web farm. I've also include the new MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler in the mix as well documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.tokens.machinekeysessionsecuritytokenhandler.aspx). My problem is that when I login a token seems to get created and cached and even pulled from cache successfully, but it doesn't seem set the thread context. Consequently, the user isn't redirected from the login page as no ClaimsPrincipal is set. If I use the default token cache, everything works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had specify a few more options on the IFormatter I was using. Specifically,

```
TypeFormat = FormatterTypeStyle.TypesAlways,
AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
```